# PHP 5.1.6 & Facebook SDK using upgrade.php still not working

Tags: php, facebook

I've written a Facebook App for a client which works fine on my own server running PHP5.2
On installing on the clients server we discovered that it was running PHP5.1.6
So no json_de/encode lib.

Client is prevented from upgrading to PHP5.2 by their server vendor and given the hack and state of their website (ancient hacked to death Joomla v1.0) probably risky.

Looking around I found upgradephp (v1.7 I've used).
Which supplies both json_encode & decode

The problem I'm stuck with is that the code is in a perpetual loop trying to get the Facebook user id:

```
$options = array("scope" => "user_birthday",
                 "redirect_uri" => "https://apps.facebook.com/".$nameSpace."/");
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($options);
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if (!$user) {
    // Require user to authenticate the app
    echo '<script>top.location.href = "' . $loginUrl . '"</script>';
}
```

This code works great on my own server, just not on the clients.
So I'm left wondering where to start debugging and how?
Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simply a configuration issue within the Facebook App panel caused by the client I did the work for.
They had wrongly entered their own web site URL omitting the preceeding "www."
When the app ran it attempted to go to the domain name without the www and was re-directed to the www.domainname. Not only that but the https was dropped for http in the re-direct.
This caused the infinite loop of re-directs as facebook doesn't allow non-https requests.